# Does Python use "chop" instead of "nearest number" rounding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision

I was under the impression that Python uses double precision arithmetic, with "nearest to" rounding. However, consider the following:

In the double precision system, the next number after `1.0` is `1.00...01 = 1 + 2**(-52)`. Now, if Python uses the "nearest to" rounding, the number `1 + 2**(-53)` should round to `1 + 2**(-52)`. However, it turns out that `1 + 2**(-53) == 1`. This would make sense if Python uses the "chop" rounding rule, but I was under the impression that nobody uses that since it biases calculations towards lower results.

Comment: From Python docs: "Floating point numbers are usually implemented using `double` in C; information about the precision and internal representation of floating point numbers for the machine on which your program is running is available in `sys.float_info`"

Comment: @gimix Thanks, I didn't know about that command. I'm not sure, but I think that as long as the machines we use follow IEEE-754 with "nearest to" rounding, the issue above shouldn't occur on any machine.

Comment: `1+2**(-52)` is not "nearer" to `1+2**(-53)` than 1. The "standard" rounding mode in IEEE754 rounds half-way cases to the "more even" number.

Comment: Python itself doesn't make any guarantees here - for the CPython reference implementation, the behaviour is whatever's picked up from the C implementation (specifically the C `double` type), which is _usually_ whatever behaviour is inherited from the CPU, which (for `double`) is _usually_ based on IEEE 754 binary64 format and some approximation to IEEE 754 semantics. But with IEEE 754 semantics, the default round-ties-to-even rounding mode would have the effect that you observe.

Comment: (Try `1 + 2**-54` to observe that Python almost certainly _isn't_ using the "chop" rounding rule on your system.)

Comment: See [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for how python rounds using the built in function.  Note pay particular attention to how it handles floats

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I think you mean `1 + 3*2**-54`. `1 + 2**-54` is one-quarter of the way from `1` to `1 + 2**-52` and will round to `1` with any of truncate, round-to-nearest, or round-downward. `1 + 3*2**-52` is three-quarters of the way and will round to `1 + 2**-54` with only round-to-nearest of those three.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks, yes. I wasn't thinking (or typing) clearly.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for your comment; but what does "more even" mean? Why is `1.0` more even than `1.0 + 2**-52`?

Comment: @user56202: Every finite non-zero binary floating-point number can be written uniquely in the form `m * 2**e` with `m` an odd integer. The bigger `e` is, the "more even" the number is. (And by extension, zero is the "most even" number of all.) Number theorists formalise this notion using the [2-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). But for a more down-to-earth view, just look at the least significant bit of the significand: for any two neighboring finite floats, that LSB will be `0` for one of the floats and `1` for the other. The one with the `0`  is the more even one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python documentation is not strict about how floating-point arithmetic is handled. Some Python implementations use IEEE 754 with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even.

In the IEEE-754 binary64 format, also known as the “double precision” format, 1+2<sup>−53</sup> is the midpoint between 1 and the next representable number, 1+2<sup>−52</sup>. So this is a tie, and the round-to-even rule applies. The significand for 1 is 1.000…000<sub>2</sub>, and the significand for 1+2<sup>−52</sup> is 1.000…001<sub>2</sub>. The former is even, so the tie-breaking rule chooses it, and the result is 1.

Consider instead 1+3•2<sup>−54</sup>. This is three-quarters of the way from 1 to 1+2<sup>−52</sup>. So rounding it to the nearest representable value will produce 1+2<sup>−52</sup>. For `print(1 == 1+3*2**-54)`, your Python implementation will likely print “False”.